# How do multiple copies of Merrow Commerce interact?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I have more than one copy of [Merrow Commerce](http://magiccards.info/lw/en/72.html) in play, they both trigger during my end step. Can I take actions after the first one resolves, but before the second one does? I'm thinking of something like tapping my [Silvergill Douser](http://magiccards.info/lw/en/87.html) and [Merfolk Thaumaturgist](http://magiccards.info/pc/en/56.html) to pick off an opponent's creatures, then having them untap again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well yes you can. These are triggered abilities

> 603.1. Triggered abilities have a trigger condition and an effect. They are written as "[Trigger condition], [effect]," and begin with the word "when," "whenever," or "at." They can also be expressed as "[When/Whenever/At] [trigger event], [effect].

Multiple triggers are put on the stack, and after one resolves, you get priority as the active player.

> 116.3b The active player receives priority after a spell or ability (other than a mana ability) resolves.

Comment: Keep in mind Merrow Commerce is different then cards like Seedborn Muse or Prophet of Kruphix, because Merrow Commerce is a triggered ability, and as noted by Ivo, any time a triggered ability goes on the stack, players have a chance to respond before the ability resolves. Seedborn Muse and Prophet of Kruphix on the other hand are static abilities, and thus do not stack, unlike Merrow Commerce which is a triggered ability and thus will stack.